# Swapping suffix and prefix of collection

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a list `L` (in the general sense, not `std::list`) of numbers and I also have `i` which is the index of the smallest element in `L`. I want to swap the two partitions separated by index `i`. What standard data structure and what operations should I perform such that I can do this as efficiently as possible (preferably in constant time)?

An example: let `L` be `9 6 -4 6 12`. The smallest value is `L[2] = -4`, so `i = 2`. After swapping the two partitions, I want `L` to be `-4 6 12 9 6`.

The list will be pretty large (up to 10<sup>3</sup> elements) and I will also have to traverse it multiple times (up to 10<sup>3</sup> traversions in the worst case), so using `std::list` is not a good idea due to caching issues. On the other hand, `std::vector` will make it difficult to swap the two partitions. Is `std::deque` a good choice for this?

Comment: Do you even need to actually move the data around? You can just create two ranges (denoted by iterators, but encapsulating this never hurts) and make note to iterate the two ranges correctly. If this can get split/rotated a number of times, just make a special iterator that keeps track of several ordered subranges and upon iterating just traverses through these ranges.

Comment: @GManNickG I might just do that. :)

Comment: Also, list can have improved locality if you give it a custom allocator that allocates from sizeable chunks (freelist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects to your problem:

1- **Constant time swap**: Conceptually speaking, the best approach will be a [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) (`std::list`) in terms of swapping.

Since your data is big, nodes will always remain at their initial places in the memory, and you will only alter some constant number of pointers to do the type of swap your are mentioning.

2- **Locality**: We all know that a contiguously allocated space in memory is better for cache performance. This leans towards `std::vector`.

**What is in the middle?**
Resizable contiguous chunks of memory that can be allocated through a custom allocator. There are numerous ways to design these. An [example](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/improving-performance-with-custom-pool-a/184406243).

Comment: Totally agreed, and if you already have a pointer the node with this `i` index, then the swap actually costs nothing but reassigning several pointers.

Comment: `std::list` **is** a doubly-linked list and apparently OP is running into caching issues with that.

Comment: Apparently, OP has not tested it yet, but is already speaking about caching issues.